# JPA Criteria: Is there any way to create a specification for exact match with list?

Tags: java, jpa, specifications

For example, I have a class user like

```
class User{
private String id;
private List<Company> companies;
}
```

And a class company

```
class Company{
private String id;
}
```

Both are entities and Im triyinng to do filter users by the exact match of companies by id with specification like

```
Specification<User> -> (root,query,builder) ->{
         Join<User,Company> companyJoin = root.join("companies");
          return builder.equal(companyJoin.get("id"),companyIdList);
        }
```

I don't want to use builder.in because I want an exact match of the user companies ids, like do:
user.getCompanies().stream().map(Company::getId).equals(companyIdList)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Join<User, Company> companyJoin = root.join("companies");

        // Create a predicate to match company IDs
        Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[companyIdList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < companyIdList.size(); i++) {
            predicates[i] = builder.equal(companyJoin.get("id"), companyIdList.get(i));
        }

        // Combine all predicates using AND
        Predicate finalPredicate = builder.and(predicates);

        return finalPredicate;
    };
```